# Python - Regex not working with a list of invalid characters?

Tags: python, regex

I'm making a validator for an email for a project.

```
  email = input("Enter an email address: ")

  if re.match("[~!#$%^&*()_+{}:;\']+$", email):
        print("Test 7 - Failed! The email has invalid characters!")
        test7 = "failed"
    else:
        print("Test 7 - Passed! The email has no invalid characters!")
        test7 = "passed"
```

If I enter something like anyemail£()@gmail.com then it still says that it is valid? I know it must be an issue with the re.match, however could someone explain the problem?

I also tried using a list and using the find command to find the particular invalid characters.

Comment: A word of advice: Don't try to validate emails. It's horrifically hard, and isn't worth the time trying.

Comment: I'm sure there's an API or module to do that for you, like this one: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the kind words, but it's part of my Computer Science project. I was aware of the module, but sadly I have to do it manually. :P

Comment: If you want to disallow backslashes, use double backslash since a single backslash is interpreted as an "escape" in regex which means to interpret the next character as a literal rather than as a potential regex character (like ] for example which would normally end a character class if it wasn't escaped properly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking if the *whole* string consists of the special characters (since `re.match` is searching for a pattern match at the beginning of the string and you have `$` end-of-string anchor at the end of your pattern).

Remove the `+$` and use `re.search` to check if a string (email) contains *at least one special character*.

```
import re
email = 'anyemail£()@gmail.com'
if re.search("[~!#$%^&*()_+{}:;\']", email):
    print("Test 7 - Failed! The email has invalid characters!")
    test7 = "failed"
else:
    print("Test 7 - Passed! The email has no invalid characters!")
    test7 = "passed"
# ==> Test 7 - Failed! The email has invalid characters!
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/fWydGP)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the reason stribizhev suggested, some of those characters have meaning when used in a regular expression, which means you would need to escape them with a backslash (it's a little hard to tell, for instance, if you are allowed backslashes in your email based on the above regex)

If you are just looking for invalid characters, it's much easier to do it without regex. For example, you could do something like this:

```
invalid_chars = r"\~!#$%^&*()_+{}:;"
for char in email:
    if char in invalid_chars:
        # fail the test
        pass
```

However, I would recommend using a whitelist of characters for this. There are a lot of strange characters out there.

Comment: Thank you. I might do that if I decide to get rid of regex from the project completely.